# Keras input_shape for conv2d for 2d tabular data of regression problem?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the CNN on a regression problem using Keras

```
> x_train2 = x_train.values.reshape(list(x_train.shape) + [1])  
> input_shape = x_train2.shape model = Sequential()
> model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu', input_shape = input_shape))
```

> output of x_train2.shape is (8000, 28, 1) and output of x_train.shape is (8000, 28)

The problem is that Input_shape should be a 4dim vectors but since the date is tabular so we have 2d data
I have tried this transformation to convert my 2d data but still have some issues

```
x_train2 = x_train.values.reshape(list(x_train.shape) + [1])
```

Any idea what am I missing or is it not possible to user the Keras Conv2D function for 2d data
This is the error i am getting

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_15 is incompatible with the
> layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [32,
> 28, 1]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you exactly tell what issue you have?

Comment: try `x_train2 = x_train.values.reshape(list(x_train.shape) + [1] + [1])`